# Retrieving all of url from document text(content)

Tags: javascript, jquery, seo

I'm developing tool to check status of all type of resources like js, css, img etc and other urls for given website.

For e.g. Given url: www.abc.com
Then I need to check status of all type of resources and urls for www.abc.com

For that I'm using jquery ajax... So as result, I will get html content of that url (abc.com)

But problem is how find all urls from that html content ? I tried lot of ways but can't figure out how do I get.

Please provide someone some good solution for that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `.each()` to iterate `img` , `link`, `script` elements ; retrieve `src` or `href` attribute values

```
$("img, link, script").each(function() {
  // do stuff with `this.src` or `this.href`
  console.log(this.src || this.href)
})
```

Comment: This is relatively easiest solution! there may be other possibilities for having urls in other tags like form, iframe etc. so we cannot query tags statically.

Comment: _"there may be other possibilities for having urls in other tags like form, iframe etc. so we cannot query tags statically"_ Try substituting `$("[src],[href],[method],[action]")` selector for `$("img, link, script")` selector , add check for `method` , `action` attributes, if necessary, within `.each()` callback

Comment: That's better idea. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

```
  $('a, img, link, script').each(function () {
        console.info($(this).attr('href'));
        console.info($(this).attr('src'));
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all "URLs" with pure JavaScript.

**HTML:**

```
<a href="www.google.com">1</a>
<br>
<a href="www.facebook.com">2</a>
<br>
<a href="www.yahoo.com">3</a>
<br>
<a href="www.bing.com">4</a>
<br>
<a href="www.youtube.com">5</a>
<br>
<a href="www.iRanOutOfNames.com">6</a>
<br>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function getURLs(url) {
  //create an empty array
  var array = [];
  // get all <a> tags
  //note: you can do that with <img/> tags or any
  //I only used the <a> tag for the sake of time
  url = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  //loop through all of the elements
  for (var i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {
    //when done, add all the elements inside the empty array
    array.push(url[i].href);
  }
  //alert them
  alert(array);
}
//call the function
getURLs();
```

Demo: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/waj9a50h/)